# 405 when connecting to webhook callback url for leadgen

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, netsuite

when trying the lead ads testing tool, i am receiving 405 error. the method is POST and I am sure that my callback url is accepting a POST method. can anyone enlighten me to resolve this error?

Another note is that the callback url is a netsuite external suitelet link, so NS gurus might be able to help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59024328/3230114) but basically NetSuite external suitelets require that the User Agent in the request header claims to be a web browser. The best workaround I have found is to use a middleware lambda function to proxy the request.

Comment: Hi. I tried changing the webhook url to a webhook site (https://webhook.site/da2458e0-3f91-448a-ad88-a976a3f53792) and it went through. below are the stats:

accept */*
user-agent Webhooks/1.0
content-type application/json
connection close
x-hub-signature sha1=6933ddeabd25c9a886c95d2990936c9976cd5dfb
host webhook.site

you can see that there is a user-agent in the header for the request that is being received

for netsuite though, i can't find where to look for those stats since the script is not being triggered at all

Comment: thanks for this. this is now resolved! i've learned something new!